# Nested has_many model in form repeats on Edit or if form has validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

If you have the following two models and using the simple_form gem to create a form:

```
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :poll_options, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_options
end

class PollOption < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :poll
end
```

The controller:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @poll = Poll.new
        @poll.poll_options.build
    end

    def edit
    end

    private
        def poll_params
           # params.fetch(:poll, {}).permit(:poll_options_attributes)
           # params.require(:poll).permit!
           params.require(:poll).permit(:title, poll_options_attributes: [ :id, :destroy, :poll_id, :label ])
        end
end
```

The form:

```
= simple_form_for(@poll) do |f|
    = f.input :title, required: true
    = f.simple_fields_for :poll_options do |option_a|
        = option_a.input :label
    = f.simple_fields_for :poll_options do |option_b|
        = option_b.input :label
```

If I submit this on purpose without a required field (label), the page reloads with 4 options, and I submit again, 6 options, etc. For some reason it keeps adding two more to the form.

Also, editing a poll loads 4 options to begin with instead of the 2 saved in the database (it shows all possible combinations of the options).

Any idea on why this would be happening?

Banging my head against the wall for 2 days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your controller permitted params please. Did you add `:id` to `poll_options_attributes`?

Comment: @cnnr Updated with params. I've tried both `params.fetch(:poll, {}).permit(:poll_options_attributes)` and `params.require(:poll).permit!`

Comment: How is your update method look like?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, finally figured it out. Here is the solution...

In the controller action, build it twice:

```
2.times do
  @poll.poll_options.build
end
```

In the view, only loop **once**. As apparently you can't have two loops to get two instances of the nested form:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :poll_options do |options|
    = options.input :label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private
def poll_params
  params.require(:poll).permit(poll_options_attributes: [:id, :destroy, ...other poll option params])
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
def new
  @poll = Poll.new
  @poll.poll_options.build unless @poll.poll_options.any?
end
```

**UPDATE 2**
Change `simple_form` helper to `simple_nested_form` (don't forget about js in your application.js)

I've no idea anymore, sorry.

Comment: Still getting the same issue if I submit a `new` form without some required fields, comes back to the form with the needed errors shows, and still repeats the options x2 again

Comment: Just tried `@poll.poll_options.build unless @poll.poll_options.any?`.. still the same issue :(

Comment: @Jacob Last update about form helper. I'm afraid, that's all.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help! That didn't fix it either but I deeply appreciate your help!